# Xcode 14.4 Sims XCUITest Get Simulator Alert Data Error - internal ObjC exception breakpoint

Tags: ios, xcode12, xcuitest, xctestcase

Using Xcode 12.4 Simulator 14.4

For the alert displayed below, I have the following function in my XCUITests that I use to pull the static text displayed on the System Alert:

```
 _ = addUIInterruptionMonitor(withDescription: "", handler: { (alert) -> Bool in
        var data = alert.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex.map {$0.label}

        ...
    })
```

[image]

This worked when using Xcode 11.3 Sims 13.3; however, I just upgraded Xcode and now it crashes on when running the map function and gives the following error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-8)..The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

If I put a breakpoint, I can see the following:

```
po alert.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex.count -> returns 3
po alert.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex[0].label -> returns "Allow “X” to use your location?"
po alert.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex[1].label -> returns "Your location is used to find and display nearby X facilities."
po alert.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex[2] -> returns StaticText, {{32.0, 12.0}, {72.5, 16.0}}, label: 'Precise: On'
```

However, when I run the following (or runs during my test), it fails but as you can see from above, it does have a static text element at that position:

```
po alert.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex[2].label -> No matches found for Element at index 2 from input {(
StaticText)} error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-8)
```

If I remain in the console and rerun the same call again, it then works though:

```
po alert.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex[2].label -> "Precise: On"
```

Does anyone know what causes this error or a solution for how I can handle it in my test?

Answer (score 0):

As this alert is "outside" your application and everything works when you debug/pause execution, I have to think this is something to do with synchronization.

Do you have anything waiting for the alert to fully display? I don't usually trust the UIInterruptionHandler to do more than auto-dismiss an alert not under test.

I'm using a page object model and typically wait for new pages in the initializer using something like `_ = XCUIApplication().alerts.firstMatch.waitForExistence(timeout: 2.0)`

That doesn't explain why your example of calling it twice in the console works, but timing is where I'd be looking. I feel that's the only time I ever see errors like this.

It could also be related to the map not being static or loading slowly and therefore changing the accessibility after XCUITest thinks it has finished loading and proceeds. Throwing in a nice long `Thread.sleep` would be the easiest way to debug that.

Comment: I did have a wait for the alert and I also just added a 15 second wait just to verify that as well, and the same result occurs.  For some reason, it has an issue with trying to pull the label text for the "Precise On" element for the map.  It only occurs for this element and only the first time .label is called.  It returns the element if I call po alert.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex[2] but .label on that fails.  After the first attempt, I can keep making the call in the terminal for it successfully and it returns "Precise On".

Comment: Very odd. The million dollar question then - should your automation suite be asserting system alerts? If it is broken, your team isn't going to be able to fix it. Sure, you may need to control the alert, but assert its text? Possibly outside the scope of what you should be doing.

Comment: I'm not asserting it actually.  I just use the text to determine which system alert is being displayed and to dismiss it correctly based on our needs.  I can 'hack it' another way to only pull the text of the first element or something, but just was trying to figure out why this was breaking now.  Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: Ah, I understand. I've few enough alerts I'm able to code them all individually without making too much of a mess.

Comment: Not necessarily helpful, but I did also notice that when checking existence of the alert or existence of buttons on the alert, it will show this error in the console " Ignoring failure to get hierarchy for remote element in process 35760 (Error getting main window kAXErrorServerNotFound)"  but it doesn't cause a crash and will still continue past the existence check.

Comment: Really feels like a race condition to me.